# How to make the key value in object notation

Tags: javascript, json, semantics

```
let records = [
    {
        "fieldApiName": "Store__c",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        
        "fieldApiName": "Portal__c",
        "enabled": false
    }
];
```

I would like to get the records in a set of key values from the above as like object notation from the values

{Store__c : true , Portal__c : false}

Comment: So is the desired output an object or a type...? (edit: nevermind, my brain was in TypeScript mode)

Comment: its should get in object @vr.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @CodeThing I have tried to make it in object enteries to find and also slice to convert into object with in find but not getting the above one

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(records.map(r => [r.fieldApiName, r.enabled]))`...

Comment: @crice Thank its worked now.  I have also tried to similar but small mistake i have done

Answer (score 0):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array of objects. In each iteration get the object's [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and assign the field as a key on the accumulator, and the enabled flag as its value.

```js
let records=[{fieldApiName:"Store__c",enabled:!0},{fieldApiName:"Portal__c",enabled:!1}];

const out = records.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const [field, enabled] = Object.values(obj);
  acc[field] = enabled;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: what the point adding const's if u can just take obj props `acc[obj.fieldApiName] = obj.enabled;`?

Comment: Personal preference.